# ShortCutKey on NavigatePage

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

I've got a question about the [ShortcutKey Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/properties/devenv-shortcutkey-property).

When I add a Shortcut to an Action on a Card- or Listpage.
-> The Shortcut works perfectly.

But when I add a Shortcut to an Action on a NavigatePage.
-> The same Shortcut used above doesn't work for example for the Action "back".

[Structure of my NaviagtePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUZUW.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? (BC190, OnPrem)

`ShortCutKey = 'Shift+Ctrl+D';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is the Business Central menu design. Shortcut keys apply only to menu actions. Quoting Microsoft documentation:

> ShortcutKey Property
> Sets a shortcut key for selecting a menu item.

Wizard pages do not display menu ribbon, but show actions as buttons in the footer bar, so shortcut keys don't work on these actions. There is no official confirmation in any documentation, but it can be indirectly confirmed by the structure of wizard pages in the Microsoft BaseApp, none of which have action shortcuts defined.